# SUMIFS using DATES in Excel Tables

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am encountering a problem using SUMIFS using dates as criteria. However, the formula I have made works in ranges but not in tables. Kindly help me out in it. Here is the query.

The formula is as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(Table2[Credit],Table2[Date],">="&'Summary Sheet'!$C$7,Table2[Date],"<"&'Summary Sheet'!$D$7,Table2[Account Head],[@[EXPENSE HEADS]])
```

where [Table2] is the table where data is located. [Summary Sheet] is the sheet where the result is required. [EXPENSE HEADS] is the table column in [Summary Sheet].

Kindly review and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifically formatting all of your dates identically, preferably as integers, in your `SUMIFS` formula. Something like:

```
VALUE(TEXT(Table2[Date], "0"))
```

and

```
VALUE(TEXT('Summary Sheet'!$C$7, "0"))
```

Or post some sample data for a better opportunity to help you.